# ¿Cómo puedo guardar varias letras en una misma variable?

Tags: python, funcion

Estoy tratando de guardar en la variable "vocal" las vocales separándolas por comas, pero
python me lo toma como un texto en completo.

```
letra = input(str("Introduzca una letra: "))
vocal = "a","e","i","o","u"

def abc(letra,vocal):
    if letra == vocal:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")    

abc(letra,vocal)
```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir que la variable tome a las letras por separadas?

Comment: Puedes guardarlas en una cadena `vocales="aeiou"` y para comprobar si la letra es una vocal miras si la letra está dentro de esa cadena, con `if letra in vocales`

Comment: Perfecto gracias.

Comment: Para aclarar conceptos, en Python esto: `a = 1, 2, 3` es lo mismo que `a = (1, 2, 3)`. O sea, se está declarando un arreglo llamado [tupla](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple). Para probarlo: `type(a)`, da como resultado: `<class 'tuple'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código se puede corregir y reducir:

```
def abc(letra):
    return letra.lower() in "aeiou"
```

La función reduce la letra a minúsculas y luego usa el operador "in" para verificar si la letra es parte de la secuencia "aeiou"

Una secuencia puede ser una lista, una tupla y también una cadena.

Al final, la función retorna `True` o `False` según la letra sea vocal o no.

Es mala práctica que las funciones impriman directamente el resultado; eso impide su uso en otras situaciones donde no se desea mostrar el resultado.

#### Demo

Tampoc necesitas hacer `str("Introduzca una letra: ")`, pues el texto ya es un string.

```
def abc(letra):
    return letra.lower() in "aeiou"

letra = input("Introduzca una letra: ")
if abc(letra):
    print("Es vocal")
else:
    print("No es vocal")
```

produce:

```
Introduzca una letra: h
No es vocal

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

la clave esta en utilizar el operador especial "in" en vez de el de comparación "==" y al hacer la  variable "vocal" una tupla (también puedes hacerlo con un str).

```
letra = input(str("Introduzca una letra: "))
vocal = ("a","e","i","o","u")

def abc(letra,vocal):
    if letra in vocal:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")    

abc(letra,vocal)
```

Si utilizaras tu código al poner aeiou te saldria TRUE, pero en AEIOU FALSE. También en mi código pasaría a TRUE, pero A FALSE. Esto ocurre porque es case sensitive, añade en la tupla las vocales en mayusculas para que eso no pase.

Comment: O tambien puedes hacer letra.lower() in vocal. Es decir, pasar la letra a minusculas y buscarla en la tupla.

Comment: Perfecto muchísimas gracias por la aportación.